# How to create a generic function for rotating with JavaScript canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, 2d

I'm working on building some JavaScript components to handle generic canvas drawing, and I'm having a hard time with getting rotations to work. I have a function similar to this (this one being simplified quite a bit).

```
function drawThing (ctx, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, rotation, drawFn) {
    // `ctx` is the 2d canvas context
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath(); // Not sure if this is needed
    ctx.translate(posX, posY); // What do I use here?
    ctx.rotate(rotation); // rotation is in radians
    drawFn(ctx, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY);
    ctx.restore();
}
function exampleDrawFn (ctx, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
    ctx.fillRect((posX - sizeX/2), (posY - sizeY/2), sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

I can't figure out what to use for the translate parameters; or perhaps there's a different error somewhere.

(Although it's a bit complicated, here's the code I'm actually working on: https://github.com/rocket-boots/rocket-boots/blob/master/scripts/rocketboots/Stage.js#L423)

Answer (score 1):

The current quickest way to draw an image.

```
function drawImage (image, x, y, sizeX, sizeY, rot) {
    var xdx = Math.cos(rot);  // direction of x axis
    var xdy = Math.sin(rot);
    ctx.setTransform(
        xdx, xdy,  // set the direction of the x axis
        -xdy, xdx, // set the direction of the y axis (at 90 deg clockwise from x axis
        x, y       // set the origin the point around which to rotate
    );
    ctx.drawImage(image,- sizeX / 2, -sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

Assuming you want the image rotated around its center that is at the point x,y When done rendering images you can reset to the default transform with `ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);`

This is just quicker than...

```
function drawImage(image, x, y, sizeX, sizeY, rot){
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
    ctx.rotate(rot);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -sizeX / 2, -sizeY / 2, sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

... on FF and Chrome but that may not be true tomorrow.

Comment: just a typo in `ctx.drawImage` methods : `-sizeX / 2` and `setTransform(...)` not `}`

Comment: Unfortunately when I tried to implement this, it didn't work / didn't do the exact same thing as my function.

Comment: @luke Oh that's a shame. Sorry without more details I can not tell if you are moving the origin towards or away from the render location, or if you are relying on any previous transformation state to render your thing.

Comment: @Blindman67 -- Here's a jsfiddle comparing the two methods: https://jsfiddle.net/05636c4c/

Comment: @luke But you move the origin again. When rendering you render to the local coordinates. The object center is always at 0,0. What ever your draw related to the object is alway drawn at the same coordinates. Car front wheel @ 20,5 back wheel -20,5 car upside down does not mater wheels are still at the same point relative to the car. I moved the origin to where it was needed so you only have to call `drawFn(ctx,0,0,sizeX,sizeY)`  the pos is set in `ctx.setTransform`.

Comment: @Blindman67 - Your function changes the coordinates but doesn't change them back, so multiple calls don't work as expect. My intention was to make a generic function that can be called more than once. Sorry that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @Luke you are free to use ctx.save and restore but they are expensive operations if you do them a lot. `ctx.setTransform` replaces the current transform state and thus does not need to use save and restore. It lets you render 1000+ rotated scaled sprites per frame that you cant do when you render with save and restore. To get the default back call ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0) its much quicker than restore.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this but reversing the translation after the rotation.

```
function drawThing (ctx, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY, rotation, drawFn) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(posX, posY);
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
    ctx.translate(-posX, -posY);
    drawFn(ctx, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Curious if there's room to improve this method, but I believe this should work.